# How to pass array of Integer from jade URL to express js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am creating a array of Integer in JavaScript using Jade template engine.

I need to pass that array to Express js route when a button is clicked.

I have tried below code:

**Jade File:**

```
 //Passing the ID to function cap one by one.
td 
 input(type="checkbox", name="delete" onclick=`cap(${item.IssueID})`)
 //here i need to pass the array--> (arr) to the Express route.
 td 
   a(href=`/tracker/deleteIssues/${arr}`) Delete
    td 
      script.
      var b=1;
      var arr=[];
      function cap(id) {for(var i=b;i<b+1;i++){arr.push(id);} b++;}
```

I am not able to pass the array to Express js route.

But I can pass the id one by one could anyone tell how to pass the whole array in one go.

Code that I tried in Express js is as below:

```
//trying to pass array here in route                                    
router.get('/deleteIssues/:arr', function(req, res) {
  console.log("deleting");
  var Issue = req.params.arr[0];
  console.log(Issue);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your array as string something like:

```
${arr.join("-")}
```

then just split your array

```
arr.split("-")
```

and use it in your controller

Comment: Thanks, I tried the solution given by you but it's not working.I tried to join the array with --> "-" and with some other special character also.But it's is not working. I tried to the output in alert box and I saw even after using join. Output is--> 1,2,3,4(these are the ids that i passed in array)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, all the parameters in the URL are a string.
maybe you can cast an array to a string of the form a1, a2, a3 ... an.
And on the server side to make a split?

Comment: yes brother @isotropic_cat you are right to split the array into string but i am not able to pass even array to route in express.That's why i am unable to split and use it further.Do you know how to pass array? so that i can use it further after spliting? Thanks